# How to convert multiple array item objects to single set of array

Tags: html, angularjs

i have array like this

```
$scope.array1=[[Name:'Madhu'],[Name:'Vijay'],[Name:'Srinu']]
```

how to convert this array to this format,
i want to pass this array in columns option(in dx datagrid columns option)
so i want array format like this

```
$scope.array2=['Maadhu','vijay','srinu']
```

Comment: that's not a valid JSON I guess. It should be array of `{Name: 'Madhu'}` and not `[Name: 'Madhu']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could use the `map` extension on arrays in javascript:

```
$scope.array2 = $scope.array1.map(function(item) {
    return item.Name;
});
```

Comment: Did you verify if this code works? Because the source array itself is incorrect and cannot be parsed.

Comment: that's a good point. I assumed the inner square brackets were curlies.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the map function:

$scope.array2 = $scope.array1.map(x = x.map(y => y.Name));